# Want to print success message when chai assertion pass

Tags: automation, mocha.js, chai, supertest

i am using

assert.equal("payment_schema_validation_failed", 'payment_schema_validation_failed', 'pass')

i want to print custom message when both the assertion pass. Above line only display third parameter when the assertion fails